# How to partition the set of jobs in Quartz?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Assume i have >100 short-running jobs. I would like to know how we can partition the set of jobs by using multiple distinct schedulers in Quartz.

Could you point some links for details or examples to partition the set of Jobs?

Thanks in advance,
Kathir

Comment: Is your question still relevant?

Answer (score 0):

To make it partition following points need to take in mind

1. Jobs By Company
2. Jobs By Date Posted
3. Jobs By Category (IT/Medical/BPO... etc etc)

These are the points by which you can partition your listed jobs. that is basic partitions further as far jobs keep on increasing you should use some advance partitioning.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, i am asking the paritition from the technical perspective and not from the business perspective. assume i have already knows what are the splitups. i would like to know how we can achieve the same in Quartz framework. Samples and examples for the same.